# Pmem and huge pages

Tags: ubuntu, huge-pages

In my Ubuntu 18.04 Intel system, there are 356gb of DDR. Out of this memory, 300gb, are pre-allocated using the pmem mechanism (since we have an external HW that sends us contiguous data chunks of 10gb). 
We are accessing this memory in a totally random manner.

We've witnessed a memory tpt degradation when accessing this memory, and we came into an understanding that the many accesses/updates to the TLB are causing the performance degradation.

For this reason we are trying to mmap our pmem with huge pages, but currently without success.

Does anybody has any experience with working with huge pages over pmem? 
Maybe other solutions for our scenario?

Thanks, 
Tom.